# How to hypothesise, evaluate and communicate UI changes

Tags: case-studies

I'm looking at compiling a spread sheet to compare React frameworks. (React Semantic UI, Material UI, Ant Design...).

```
Framework, metric...    
Semantic UI                     
Material UI                     
Ant Design
```

There are some metrics which are un-opinionated tangible metrics (File size, Webpack Tree shaking,  No. components) But these don't necessarily communicate the value to the user.

Some things like Material UI (which I'm biased to) have really nice user feedback animations. I'd like to practice better UX and pragmatically evaluate these frameworks for our business use case.

How do I measure these very opinion oriented types of behaviours? Preferably without pushing to production. And communicate these findings to stakeholders?

Perhaps a more basic form of my question is "How to hypothesise the colour blue is better suited to our needs" How do I go about building a case for something design oriented like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if I got this right, you want to measure different UI frameworks besides their logistic and dev ops offering and more in terms of what they offer "design-wise", correct?

As you mention, it is quite subjective and dependant on your product's/company's requirements.

A few of things you need to know first:

1. What is your branding? In your question "How to hypothesise the colour blue is better suited to our needs", c**onsider the nature of the product you are building, the branding of the company and the tone of voice**. There are [plenty of studies](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/color-theory-for-designers-part-1-the-meaning-of-color/) in colour theory that explain which colours tend to work best for which industry, what to select if you want a more corporate look etc.
2. What are you building your product for? Is it strictly a mobile app, a desktop app or potentially both?
3. Backward compatibility. Do your users have specific browser needs that you need to cater for?

When looking into UI Frameworks I tend to look in the following:

1. The logic behind each framework's design. For example, Material is heavily focused on the paper metaphor which translates really well in mobile UIs, however, the heavy shadows and floating buttons can become distracting in a desktop app environment. Additionally, if you are planning on releasing your product on iOS devices then Material guidelines might not translate as well depending on how complex your product is.
2. Do the elements that the UI framework offers match your product's needs? e.g Do you require complex tables, gestures or other interactions that one framework might offer over another?
3. Is the UI framework accessibility friendly in terms of how it manages colours, element sizing, aria labels etc. If not, is it easy to edit these changes in or will you have to do loads of work beforehand?
4. Overall appearance. Does the general look and feel match what you are going for? Depending on branding, target user demographics and tone of voice this might limit your options.

I found [this article](https://crysberry.com/blog/choose-perfect-ui-framework/) that does a better job at explaining all this. You might find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for having an ambiguous question. Im a developer wanting to do more UX. And it really perplexes me trying to rationalise these things.

Comment: @Lex No worries, that's what this community is for.